# Why is cycles not rendering the particle system?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

In this scene i wanted to render that object as particle system and in the rendered viewport it works but int the final render not

here is the file: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the particle object (called *Circle*), go into the *Object panel > Instancing*, and enable *Show Instancer > Render*, otherwise it won't show its own particles:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much it worked!